# How to use MS Word's Dictate inside .net project?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I want to display words or sentence in a textbox based on user's voice input. I have tried Microsoft's `System.Speech.Recognition` but it is not recognizing exact word which we pronounce.

From google, I found that in MS word there is a add-in called **Dictate** and when I tried from word document it easily understood my speech and prints the exact words in Word document.

Is there any option to use this Dictate feature inside .net project either directly or using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a Nuget package called `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeechRecognition`.
You can use this one to add the speech recognition feature in your console application.

Before the package installation you have to create the `API key` of the tool you are going to use whichever it is. Insert the API key to get the whole functionable speech recognition module.

Comment: This package is deprecated.